# Az login Fails using Personal Microsoft Account - AADSTS500200

Tags: azure

For a long time was using Terraform with Azure and it worked fine. Now for any reason the az cli command it doens't work.
I'm getting follow error:

```
AADSTS500200: User account 'xxxx ' is a personal Microsoft account. Personal Microsoft accounts are not supported for this application unless explicitly invited to an organization. Try signing out and signing back in with an organizational account.
```

I've already upgrade az cli versin to 2.42 but problem perists. Even using incognito mode couldn't login to Azure.
Instead of using az login, via browser I'm able to login to azure cloud without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below commands to clear the cache.

```
az account clear
az login
```

or

```
az login --tenant [tenant id]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related with Az cloud list. The active azure cloud was "AzureUSGovernment" instead of "AzureCloud". Once enabled "AzureCloud" issue got fixed.

```
az cloud set --name AzureCloud
```